# AIR/Android NFC tags are opening the Browser

Tags: android, flash, air, nfc

I'm testing an NFC-enabled Android/AIR application using a Nexus S.

My NFC tag has a sample url on it, e.g. "http://www.google.com".

I'd like to capture the url (or any text) on the tag for use in the app.

When the tag is tapped, the phone instead opens the url in the Browser.

I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing in my manifest, or if links are always handled by the browser. I've looked at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html) and I've even added a scheme for the specific URL, but still no luck.

My manifest is below. Thanks for any input.

```
<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>

    <application android:debuggable="true">
        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>                 
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>                  
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A URL on an NFC tag is not the same as a plain text message on an NFC tag. They have different message types. Your manifest lists 2 intent filters for a plain text message (the last one will never be triggered actually, a TAG_DISCOVERED intent will never contain any data from the tag).
For matching your sample URL try instead:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>                 
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.com" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

See also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html#ndef-disc for a more detailed explanation of `NDEF_DISCOVERED` and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html for full documentation of what can go in a `<data>` element.